# s-parameter matrix analysis

Tags: rf, matrix, s-parameters

[image]

So I'm trying to figure out how I can analyze S-parameter matrices.

The i. should be pretty straightforward, though I'm not 100% sure if I am correct with what it means. I'm assuming that there's only one active, ideal part.

For ii. and iii. I'm a lot more clueless, though I can definitely see the consistences of the values.

Parts i. and ii. have two ports whereas iii. has 3 ports. iii. has only 3 different values for the real/imaginary values and the cross-section is consistent (\$S_{11}\$, \$S_{22}\$, \$S_{33}\$).

I'm not exactly sure what kind of conclusion I'm even supposed to arrive to or what I should do to approach this analysis.

Comment: The answer probably depends on the context of what you've learned in your class. You might want to use words like *gain*, *isolation*, *matching*, *return loss*, *phase shift* in your answer.

Comment: We had an additional hint for the assignment "Scattering matrix of a reciprocal network is symmetric and scattering matrix of a lossless
network is unitary:

[S]
 [S∗]

= I
where ∗
is the complex conjugate transpose of matrix S and I is the identity matrix."

Comment: That hint is probably telling you that at least one of the examples will be reciprocal and at least one will be lossless. (unless your instructor wants to be clever and throw you a red herring)

Comment: To me it looks a lot like i. is lossless, since it has no imaginary values at all, at the very least. I'll have to take a deeper dive to consider the other cases

Comment: @Grak Being unitary doesn't mean no imaginary entries.